# Exchange AirSync protocol help

Tags: exchange-server, protocols, wbxml

I'm looking for resources for the AirSync protocol for Exchange (general or even better if specifically targeted at .NET). It seems strange that it can't be found anywhere on the net.

I know it uses WBXML for parts of its communications, but that as far as I got.

Answer (score 2):

I know a certain amount about AirSync/ActiveSync :)

There are various [open specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc425499.aspx) you can download. There's a lot to wade through, although I think only the MS-AS* documents are relevant.

Are you planning to write a client or a server?

You should be aware that the various different devices which implement the protocol as clients behave in somewhat different ways...

Comment: I'm thinking about a server implementation

Comment: Okay. Have fun :) Now you've got the specifications, I suggest you ask very detailed questions rather than this sort of general one. I'll help with such questions when I can, but there may be times when it would be too commercially sensitive to do so.